# Creating new Observable list

Tags: java, observablelist

When creating a new Observable List why do we type :

```
ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

insted of

```
ObservableList<String> names = new ObservableList<String>;
```

Thanks for help :)